# I have a question on HackerRank where some test cases pass for this code, and some do not

Tags: java, data-structures

You are given a list of student information: ID, FirstName, and CGPA. Your task is to rearrange them according to their CGPA in decreasing order. If two student have the same CGPA, then arrange them according to their first name in alphabetical order. If those two students also have the same first name, then order them according to their ID. No two students have the same ID.
**Hint:** You can use comparators to sort a list of objects. See the oracle docs to learn about comparators.

**Input Format**
The first line of input contains an integer N , representing the total number of students. The next N lines contains a list of student information in the following structure:
`ID Name CGPA`

**Constraints**
2≤N≤1000
0≤ID≤1000000
5≤|Name|≤305
0≤CGPA≤4.000

The name contains only lowercase English letters. The **ID** contains only integer numbers without leading zeros. The CGPA will contain, at most, 2 digits after the decimal point.

**Output Format**
After rearranging the students according to the above rules, print the first name of each student on a separate line.

**Sample Input**
5
33 Rumpa 3.68
85 Ashis 3.85
56 Samiha 3.75
19 Samara 3.75
22 Fahim 3.76

**Sample Output**
Ashis
Fahim
Samara
Samiha
Rumpa

**This is my code;**

```
import java.util.*;

class Student{
    private int id;
    private String fname;
    private double cgpa;
    public Student(int id, String fname, double cgpa) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public double getCgpa() {
        return cgpa;
    }
}


class CombinedComparator implements Comparator<Student>{
    @Override
     public int compare(Student student1, Student student2){
         int gpaComparison = Double.compare(student2.getCgpa(), student1.getCgpa());
         
         if(gpaComparison==0){
             int fNameComparison= student1.getFname().toLowerCase().compareToIgnoreCase(student2.getFname().toLowerCase());
             if(fNameComparison==0){
                 return Integer.compare(student1.getId(), student2.getId());
             }
             return fNameComparison;
         }
         return gpaComparison;
     }
}


//Complete the code
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while(testCases>0){
            int id = in.nextInt();
            String fname = in.next();
            double cgpa = in.nextDouble();

            
            Student st = new Student(id, fname, cgpa);
            studentList.add(st);
            
            testCases--;
        }
        Collections.sort(studentList, new CombinedComparator());
        
        
          for(Student st: studentList){
            System.out.println(st.getFname());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-sort/problem

The problem states (under **Constraints**):

> The name contains only lowercase English letters.

That's a lie.
When I submitted your code (to Hackerrank), I got 5 out of 7 test cases failed. I unlocked the first failed test case and downloaded it. Here it is:

```
100
1 PdeLwCYcXHBUyDovShzHKI 1.85
2 XHjqMumVZfSW 0.18
3 zXiGscYethmwLgalEVwuSGdzxI 0.17
4 ggjwTvvaAraioUNmKKfKWwA 1.13
5 PrvDm 1.38
6 NnDGDcEQ 1.59
7 hyDbVOGaobNkXZR 2.39
8 HYasEeNIkTsDSnuMXQGDuFIZuGen 2.01
9 AVSHnKvDZorlL 3.46
10 aOdxZenFiSfZzoO 3.32
11 PnfTXKEvdJeLaciXAIooDmqlTuBxJL 1.30
12 FSXEeOwelNxMVutJDFjEzLm 0.81
13 QryjiTfrkcUGnJBnkzAWwdiqJhZqh 1.87
14 YVTVYxRUiAoFNNgHJGyF 0.70
15 dofSxfFEwPPnKwFfVsynJkBDhumIA 1.52
16 JXneisxgkeLkak 2.98
17 hjBCAXDgihUqPExDuRrJcz 1.15
18 fwXRzErDWcyKjPxbOfApVJx 1.81
19 YAmyNFyT 0.12
20 VSgQTgiqNyQMRerhQdLRUemcEQX 3.75
21 tMloJlO 1.18
22 yvOgyJLb 3.21
23 VDhZY 3.14
24 XvxXsDKIjkFJHiWTOkd 3.37
25 mcNnINTMSdpMxwTApWSJ 2.72
26 vosdf 2.00
27 DHRSaJQJdJiJBmxjmLouQ 2.80
28 KvzKzel 0.10
29 xcRgist 0.23
30 QWPwPuN 1.58
31 sydIngROEZHupsHzPFFpXhZh 3.02
32 yNXtoxp 0.78
33 bGVtEfpjOniybCxKYVrPMkqbhVYsG 3.19
34 bsbxNbUVvECrfSV 3.51
35 fRHKrHh 0.16
36 XgBjLqwusge 1.57
37 jTkQkHxwAKfyykjWiyJKTqcCUZ 2.26
38 ZZDGEToBqnxnPK 2.13
39 pVGMylZEC 2.64
40 UhhdgCqcOuWAJOFWKqsGUGw 3.62
41 keyYAGA 0.03
42 MkVKGyExPayZExpJEl 0.42
43 uMwoJFugvXGnSgaApSIzNN 3.79
44 BmnINxoKI 0.91
45 toTIoHWsZB 0.36
46 xvIUeYZMlBrRbAUxcLtzLPdjORQIYZ 0.81
47 LIaCQ 1.28
48 jadiayxBP 1.18
49 NQfoFodr 0.48
50 QumKkEcRFIdHaTHudcvHjEAYlAnkn 1.99
51 hlTgCgoFvpFUSXTssbQ 3.55
52 mzEhSqlRtxslyNZZnmCGGdvJbujoIe 0.97
53 ABAJwYeibIJQ 3.58
54 KUlxpQpgbCPp 2.61
55 XhhoNTJ 2.06
56 nTBfkiqGrAem 1.78
57 ArFnJ 1.33
58 tzqGKOBIHnl 0.86
59 gmWXph 3.85
60 KkKNPuDXiddAsnCQZgnMQyhJqB 2.47
61 PDpUZLlXiihnpYCmDCor 2.62
62 WneXKKERUBQ 1.57
63 NElkBCFZUUJBLLcVjQn 1.48
64 mdOtOeFpyLW 2.73
65 FOIzcUHOGYTBnGLn 0.02
66 ibyUYmXdfoAW 3.75
67 wCZQpyjUBfEmZpApljyxKbPv 2.04
68 fmbSzWBAFYvgvYoAfNgh 0.56
69 rAFMZelAhtAYs 0.12
70 IwQmGhDJAiExVBjUmHXAfvUDqUyksh 3.38
71 CEoQmJhGNuufStMmSAHCj 0.95
72 LtbWRlEpzNbawIIo 3.94
73 FxwndjRHEXgXaXYw 1.55
74 euKDKBZrwqODRtIyWji 2.01
75 ssLafrVwU 3.93
76 ZlusqchpsvpSimDBnocPXdgCW 1.52
77 FfMtpOUNvGKBETc 2.39
78 WJTKFI 0.36
79 bHfivIcusSyRnaovkBZazI 1.87
80 RzXoSUoHEcIH 1.73
81 dkrlgltSHdWFTvldivCmKGIRdp 0.60
82 NDnPzRMahqJNvqArVFrqrZOphOAHO 0.19
83 tVsahPGsuJFIQ 1.37
84 EcKbvrkcWEkqZZMHXnqzjTSG 2.68
85 EnSVRSXzsyWuCMVVe 2.15
86 qJOdMwks 2.09
87 tNDpFOSdpdUfUbzkcINKdHIaZxV 0.28
88 VkNpJJXfFnzBclOPwIvdabTxqSzFJ 2.97
89 SjqGgkIlXdWxmVgZkrqgaBX 1.28
90 agPfUmvm 1.79
91 oWgzOedgOdRozRaEymNOLPRCqvl 0.60
92 LdHAmtvQLIEpXoWwmhfEDmguyJ 1.61
93 hYGUutHgTzGQhWM 1.89
94 FEXmMZqytnoWRMACuad 1.15
95 wAEauaPeHuTdnyQY 0.75
96 vcGdlaKlNsEp 0.90
97 OllfZlACfxPdXgsM 1.56
98 FlbyiCXNChMaokOglrGd 0.25
99 dwBNMwtQwYeZprqQpXK 1.70
100 vZuGpylfeQrliAXfJT 2.45
```

As you can see, it does **not** contain *only lowercase English letters*.

Hence you just need to change your comparison of the [Student] name to the following:

```java
int fNameComparison= student1.getFname().compareTo(student2.getFname());
```

Once I made that change and re-submitted the code, all test cases passed.

For the sake of completeness, here is the entire solution – including the above change.

```java
import java.util.*;

class Student{
    private int id;
    private String fname;
    private double cgpa;
    public Student(int id, String fname, double cgpa) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public double getCgpa() {
        return cgpa;
    }
}

class CombinedComparator implements Comparator<Student>{
    @Override
     public int compare(Student student1, Student student2){
         int gpaComparison = Double.compare(student2.getCgpa(), student1.getCgpa());
         
         if(gpaComparison==0){
             int fNameComparison= student1.getFname().compareTo(student2.getFname());
             if(fNameComparison==0){
                 return Integer.compare(student1.getId(), student2.getId());
             }
             return fNameComparison;
         }
         return gpaComparison;
     }
}

//Complete the code
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while(testCases>0){
            int id = in.nextInt();
            String fname = in.next();
            double cgpa = in.nextDouble();
            
            Student st = new Student(id, fname, cgpa);
            studentList.add(st);
            
            testCases--;
        }
        Collections.sort(studentList,new CombinedComparator());
        for(Student st: studentList){
            System.out.println(st.getFname());
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, nearly all HackerRank problems have online solutions available. Just Google for **hackerrank** ***name of problem*** **solution**. So for your problem, I Googled:

> hackerrank java sort solution

First result was:
https://programs.programmingoneonone.com/2021/02/hackerrank-java-sort-solution.html

Answer (score -3):

It runs correctly and returns the correct output.

Here is an alternate implementation.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = in.nextInt(), i = 0;
record Student(int id, String firstName, String cgpa) {}
List<Student> a = new ArrayList<>();
do a.add(new Student(in.nextInt(), in.next(), in.next()));
while (++i < N);
a.sort((x, y) -> {
    if (x.cgpa.equals(y.cgpa))
        if (x.firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(y.firstName))
            return Integer.compare(x.id, y.id);
        else return x.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(y.firstName);
    else return y.cgpa.compareTo(x.cgpa);
});
a.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.firstName));
```

Output

```
5
33 Rumpa 3.68
85 Ashis 3.85
56 Samiha 3.75
19 Samara 3.75
22 Fahim 3.76
Ashis
Fahim
Samara
Samiha
Rumpa
```

Comment: Downvoted because code-only answers are not useful.